# ajax recursive calls on wordpress returning answers outsite the function scope

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I'm having a problem when i use an ajax function where it is used with this:

```
window.setInterval(liveDrop, 2000);
```

This trigger my ajax call every 2 secounds and check if is there is need to update something in the site.

The function works fine, but when i put something like this on `functions.php`(not only this, but as example)

```
 echo 'TEST';
```

my ajax request runned in `window.setInterval` start to print this 'test', and this `echo teste` is actually outsite the function scope on 'action:my_function' in the ajax request.

My problem is that, i receiving outsite commands in my ajax calls.

Addicional information:
 - i'm using `wp_die()`, `wp_send_json_success`.. etc 
 - I'm register my functions in the right hooks( they work fine if don't have a `echo 'test'` or anything in `admin_init_hook`)

Has anyone ever seen this happen?

UPDATE:

My ajax code:

```
function liveDrop(){
    last_drop = parseInt($('.item-drop-area').first().data('id'));

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_request.ajax_url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'action': 'live_drop',
            'last_item': last_drop
        },
    })
    .done(function(response) {


        if( typeof response.data.has_new_live_drop != 'undefined' && response.data.has_new_live_drop === true ){
            $('.dropped-area').prepend(response.data.item_droped);
            $('.drop-item-inserted').show('slow');

            last_drop += 1;

            $('.item-drop-area').last().remove();

        }



    });
}

window.setInterval(liveDrop, 2000);
```

My php function:

```
public function __construct( ){

        add_action('wp_ajax_live_drop', array($this, 'live_drop'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_live_drop', array($this,'live_drop'));

    }


    public function live_drop(){

        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sorted_items';

        $next_item = intval($_GET['last_item']) + 1;

        $new_items_check = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,user_id, item_id, crate_id FROM $table_name WHERE id = $next_item AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(current_timestamp, date)) > 15 LIMIT 1");

        if(!empty($new_items_check)){

            $html = '';

            foreach ($new_items_check as $item) { 

                $crate_img    = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $item->crate_id , 'medium' );
                $item_img     = get_the_post_thumbnail( $item->item_id, 'live-drop', ['class' => 'item-image-livedrop'] );
                $item_name    = get_the_title( $item->item_id );
                $user_avatar  = get_user_meta( $item->user_id, 'steam_avatar', true );
                $username     = get_user_meta( $item->user_id, 'steam_personaname', true);
                $steam_id     = get_user_meta( $item->user_id, 'steam_steamid', true);
                $profile_link = home_url() . '/member/' . $steam_id;

                $html .= '<div class="item-drop-area drop-item-inserted"  data-id="' .  $item->id .  '">';
                $html .= '<div class="item-live-droped">';
                $html .= '<a class="see-user-profile" href="' .  $profile_link . '">';
                $html .= '<img class="crate-image-livedrop" src="' . $crate_img . '" />';
                $html .= $item_img;
                $html .= '<img class="user-avatar-livedrop" src="' . $user_avatar . '"/>';
                $html .= '<p class="drop-item-name">' . $item_name . '</p>';
                $html .= '<div class="item-live-dropped-hover">';
                $html .= '<p class="user-live-drop">' .   $username . '</p>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '</a>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '</div>';


            }


            $data = array(
                'has_new_live_drop' => true,
                'item_droped'       => $html
            );

            wp_send_json_success( $data, 200 );

        }

        wp_send_json_error( false, 200 );

    }
```

This code works fine, but if i have let's say a 'echo teste' on my functions.php, this code will appear on the response of this ajax request, this is the problem, every 2 secounds he don't show up just the answer of the function, he show up with information which is outsite of function like a echo statement.

Comment: I don't follow, can you edit your question to include the JS and the PHP code?

Comment: sure, will update

Answer (score 2):

Plugins and your theme are loaded on every request, including AJAX, so any code in them is parsed. They need to be so that any AJAX hooks are found and executed.

Most of the code isn't executed though, because it's in functions that are hooked to hooks that aren't executed during an AJAX request. Some of it is though. If you're filtering `pre_get_posts()` in your theme or a plugin, then you probably want that filter to be run during any queries in an AJAX request. So plugins and themes need to be loaded in their entirety to do this.

But if you're running code outside a function in your theme's functions file then that's going to be executed as soon as the theme is loaded, so it will be output on the front-end and in AJAX requests. But the thing is: you shouldn't be writing code in functions.php that isn't inside a function. Just loading functions.php shouldn't cause any output.

Comment: Thank you jacob for the answer, but my problem is when i try to prevent users to access the  wp-admin for certain user roles i hook into the 'admin_init', and so every request bug and i can't block this wp-admin access, did you know if have a list of hooks that is started in ajax requests?

Comment: `is_admin` is false when AJAX requests are fired, but have you considered using the superior/easier REST API? Keep in mind that if you put code in the global scope in `functions.php` it will always execute, it'll execute on REST, it'll execute on Admin, it'll execute on AJAX, it'll execute on frontend, this is expected behaviour. TLDR don't `echo 'test';` in the global scope, run all code on actions/hooks